# splitting lists and values

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, split

Within a python script I have 2 floating values and 2 lists that I would like to write in a csv file. lonwgs84 and latwgs84 are floating values and col1s and col2s are lists. When I write the csv file with:

```
with open(ausgabe, "wb") as f:  
    datawriter = csv.writer(f)
    for each in zip(lonwgs84 , latwgs84, col1s, col2s):
        cols = each[0] , each[1], each[2] + each[3]
        datawriter.writerow(cols)
```

I get following output:

```
51.821336803,11.6756790532,"['~11:16:05.833', '$GPGGA', '091607.00', '5149.28020818', 'N', '01140.54074319', 'E', '', '', '000.01']"
```

but what I need is:

```
51.821336803,11.6756790532,~11:16:05.833,$GPGGA,091607.00,5149.28020818,N,01140.54074319,E,,,000.01
```

I tried with split, but that does only seem to work with strings. Maybe someone has an idea how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: but you can try using spit on individual each[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply slice your row to get the first 2 elements, concatenate the 3rd and 4th:

```
datawriter.writerow(each[:2] + each[3] + each[4])
```

Alternatively, *unpack* the elements first:

```
for fp1, fp2, lst1, lst2 in zip(lonwgs84 , latwgs84, col1s, col2s):
    datawriter.writerow([fp1, fp2] + lst1 + lst2)
```

Demo:

```
>>> [fp1, fp2] + lst1 + lst2
[51.821336803, 11.6756790532, '~11:16:05.833', '$GPGGA', '091607.00', '5149.28020818', 'N', '01140.54074319', 'E', '', '', '000.01']
```

You created a tuple of the first 2 elements, plus the second two elements *concatenated* with `+`:

```
cols = each[0], each[1], each[2] + each[3]
```

resulting in a nested structure of `(each[0], each[1], [elements of each[2] and each[3]])`.

Comment: thanks a for the hint, I unpacked the elements first now and that works fine for me.